# Python Multi-threading: Threads Number

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I'm currently exploring python threading's option.

I have saw this kind of example to have a thread pool

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def function(x):
    return x * x

pool = ThreadPool(4)
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
pool.map(function, array)
```

The only problem is that I want a way to know in which thread is the function running. Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `threading.current_thread()`:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from threading import current_thread

def function(x):
    return (current_thread().name, x * x)

pool = ThreadPool(4)
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(pool.map(function, array))
```

This produces a result like:

```
[('Thread-1', 1), ('Thread-1', 4), ('Thread-1', 9), ('Thread-3', 16), ('Thread-3', 25), ('Thread-3', 36), ('Thread-1', 49), ('Thread-4', 64), ('Thread-2', 81), ('Thread-2', 100)]
```